# Change NavigationStack-path from ViewModel?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to implement the MVVM-architecture in my little app and I am confused about how to update the `path` of my `NavigationStack` from the ViewModel. My `path` is a `@Published` property and gets inserted via an `@EnvironmentObject` into my View. Via a button I am doing an API-call with the corresponding function being located in my ViewModel.
If the API-call is successfull, I want to change the `path` of my NavigationStack. But I can't access the `@Published` property inside the ViewModel!
I could use a completion handler but that is not clean MVVM, right?

**Model:**

```
enum pathCases:  Hashable {
    case Home, Settings
}

class Navigation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [pathCases] = []
}
```

**View:**

```
//...
@EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
//...
NavigationStack(path: $navigation.path) {
   //...
   Button("Make API-Call") {
       myApiFunction()
   }
   //...
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
@MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func myApiFunction() {
       //change the array navigation.path - how?
    }
}
```

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is already the view model so it is already MVVM you don't need any objects. Just learn state and binding, break up your view data into small View structs and you'll be fine.

Comment: Have a look at this **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)
 
 Your `func myApiFunction()` is used to change the `path` in your `class Navigation: ObservableObject`,
 therefore that function should be in that class. Then call the function such as: `Button("Make API-Call") { navigation.myApiFunction() }`. 
 With you current unwieldy setup, you could try using a parameter, `func myApiFunction(path: $navigation.path) { //change path }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `@Published` variable in your viewModel which your View listens to. And you can use the `.onChange` observer to append your path into the Navigation environmentObject

**View:**

```
//...
@EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
//...
NavigationStack(path: $navigation.path) {
   //...
   Button("Make API-Call") {
       myApiFunction()
   }
   //...
}.onChange(of: viewModel.resultOfApi) { resultOfApi in
        if resultOfApi {
            // append to navigation.path here
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
@MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published resultOfApi = false // for example
    func myApiFunction() {
       resultOfApi = true
    }
}
```

It is important to understand that the new APIs are "data-driven" so your changes should modify the state of some data container (which is your ViewModel here, and the View simply reacts to it based on the state of the data)